# How do i create a new column in a data frame with zero rows (in R) ?

Tags: r, rows, rstudio

I am running a loop. 
In this loop new data frame(with same number and name of columns) is created everytime and is appended in the previous table. 
Ex: 
for i = 1

```
i have df1 = df1(n rows, m column)
df1$new_col <- "some value"
 df = rbind(df0,df1)
for i = 2 
i have df1 = df1(0 rows, m column)
df1$new_col <- "some val"
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "new_col", value = "some_value") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

how do i add a new column to a  df with zero rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
df<-data.frame()
dim(df)
x<-1:100
df=rbind(df,x)
df=t(df)
dim(df)
```